# Unable to get XElement Descendant element value with namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

In the following code I am getting the value of Id as null, even though its there in the xml snippet. After getting the iterable, looks like it needs something more to get out the value. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
 var str =
  @"
<CustomerCareReport xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects.FireEms' xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
  <RecordAction xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects'>Edit</RecordAction>
  <FireIncident xmlns:a='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects.FireIncidents'>
    <a:Address xmlns:b='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects.Addresses'>
      <b:City>SomeCity</b:City>
      <b:HouseNumber>4019</b:HouseNumber>
      <b:Id>1651880</b:Id>
      <b:Lat>47.573911198</b:Lat>
      <b:LocationType>Address</b:LocationType>
      <b:Lon>-122.169529554</b:Lon>
      <b:State xmlns:c='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects.ValidationSets'>
        <RecordAction xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects'>Relate</RecordAction>
        <c:Description>Washington</c:Description>
        <c:EntryValue>WA</c:EntryValue>
        <c:FilterString>WA Washington</c:FilterString>
        <c:Id>85</c:Id>
        <c:Inactive>false</c:Inactive>
        <c:SetId>1021</c:SetId>
      </b:State>
      <b:StreetName>FACTORIA</b:StreetName>
      <b:StreetSuffix>SE</b:StreetSuffix>
      <b:StreetType>BLVD</b:StreetType>
      <b:Venue>
        <b:VenueName>BE</b:VenueName>
      </b:Venue>
      <b:VenueName>BE</b:VenueName>
      <b:Zip>98006</b:Zip>
    </a:Address>
    <a:FDID xmlns:b='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects.Jurisdictions'>
      <RecordAction xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects'>Relate</RecordAction>
      <b:Ori>17M02</b:Ori>
    </a:FDID>
    <a:IncidentNumber>2016-00000071</a:IncidentNumber>
  </FireIncident>
  <OtherInformation>
    <RecordAction xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects'>Add</RecordAction>
    <Documents xmlns:a='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects.Documents'>
      <a:Document>
        <RecordAction xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects'>Add</RecordAction>
        <a:CheckOutMachine>TROPPLT</a:CheckOutMachine>
        <a:Contents>Z2dn</a:Contents>
        <a:Description>yoyo</a:Description>
        <a:FileType xmlns:b='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects.ValidationSets'>
          <RecordAction xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects'>Relate</RecordAction>
          <b:Description>Notepad</b:Description>
          <b:EntryValue>txt</b:EntryValue>
          <b:FilterString>txt Notepad</b:FilterString>
          <b:Id>1</b:Id>
          <b:Inactive>false</b:Inactive>
          <b:SetId>2574</b:SetId>
        </a:FileType>
        <a:Id>0e2821b0-9430-40a8-8964-443cdeeda018</a:Id>
        <a:Name>yoyo</a:Name>
        <a:UsageKey>0</a:UsageKey>
        <a:UsageType>56</a:UsageType>
      </a:Document>
      <a:Document>
        <RecordAction xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects'>Add</RecordAction>
        <a:CheckOutMachine>TROPPLTBKOLLURU</a:CheckOutMachine>
        <a:Contents>ZmhmaA0KZmZmDQpmamZqZmpmDQo=</a:Contents>
        <a:Description>test 2</a:Description>
        <a:FileType xmlns:b='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects.ValidationSets'>
          <RecordAction xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects'>Relate</RecordAction>
          <b:Description>Notepad</b:Description>
          <b:EntryValue>txt</b:EntryValue>
          <b:FilterString>txt Notepad</b:FilterString>
          <b:Id>1</b:Id>
          <b:Inactive>false</b:Inactive>
          <b:SetId>2574</b:SetId>
        </a:FileType>
        <a:Id>9b42f7e0-e0b3-4e83-a466-5862e9cb5bbe</a:Id>
        <a:Name>test 2</a:Name>
        <a:UsageKey>0</a:UsageKey>
        <a:UsageType>56</a:UsageType>
      </a:Document>
    </Documents>
  </OtherInformation>
  <Response>
    <Apparatus xmlns:a='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects.Units'>
      <RecordAction xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects'>Relate</RecordAction>
      <a:Id>-1672</a:Id>
      <a:UnitNumber>E1</a:UnitNumber>
    </Apparatus>
    <ResponseNumber>1600000071E1</ResponseNumber>
  </Response>
  <Time>
    <CallDatetime>2016-07-01T12:26:34.277-04:00</CallDatetime>
    <DispatchNotifiedDatetime>2016-07-01T12:26:34.277-04:00</DispatchNotifiedDatetime>
  </Time>
</CustomerCareReport>
";

            var xelement = XElement.Parse(str);
            XNamespace ns = xelement.Name.Namespace;
            var documents = xelement.Descendants(ns + "Documents");

            foreach (XElement document in documents)
            {
                if (document.Name.LocalName.Equals("Id"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(document.Value);

                }

            }
```

Comment: `foreach (XElement document in documents.Descendants())` ?

Comment: The arre no Ids in element Document.  So try : foreach (XElement document in xelement.Descendants())

Comment: Did a quick check, didnt help. Btw I also have to distinguish between the two Ids in the document. you will see one has integet value and another has GUID value in the outer nesting.  I need to reach in and get only the Id with the GUID value in it. i am guessing namespacing has to be set to distinguish between the two.

Comment: so I want to reach a:Id not b:Id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, there are no child elements of `Documents` that have a local name of `Id`. This is the child of the child `a:Document` elements.

Using the right namespaces, your query should look like this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects.FireEms"
XNamespace a = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foo.Bar.Frameworks.Reporting.Stack.Infrastructure.DataObjects.Documents"

var element = XElement.Parse(str);

var ids = element
    .Descendants(ns + "Documents")
    .Descendants(a + "Id");
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L1mpsA) for a working demo.

Comment: Thank you so much Charles. I only knew about JSFiddle. +1 for pointing me to dotnetfiddle. I already marked your response as answered but i hav a further question. I am able to get the root namespace with xelement.Name.Namespace without hardcoding it. But I did have to hardcode the a: namespace in the query. Is there a way to get that also using Name.Namespace?

Comment: Not really. But you're hard coding the local names (Documents, Id), so why not the namespaces? They both make up a qualified name, and neither are likely to change.